# css parent div and child div not playing properly

Tags: css, jquery, css-float

i have a parent div that has about six divs inside side by side. Everything works fine except when i added a little bit of jQuery to it.

Now the parent div doesn't expand as before. I made the parent div `relative` and the child divs `absolute` but the parent div just wont stretch open.

**jQuery**

```
$(".child").click(function() { 
  var mypos, otherpos, $this; 

  // Move to the target element 
  $this = $(this); 
  pos = $this.offset(); 
  otherpos = $('selector_for_other_element').offset(); 
  pos.left = otherpos.left - pos.left; 
  pos.top  = otherpos.top  - pos.top; 
  $this.animate({ 
    left: pos.left + "px", 
    top:  pos.top  + "px" 
  }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
  .child{
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute
  }
  .parent {
    width: 770px;
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: none;
  }
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">content</div>
  <div class="child">>content</div>
  <div class="child">>content</div>
  <div class="child">>content</div>
  <div class="child">>content</div>
  <div class="child">>content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It precisely because you made the parent `relative` and the children `absolute` that it does not stretch. Once you make something `absolute` it is no longer in the document flow, and does not affect the other elements (including your parent div).

Comment: First of all, it should be $(".child"), not $("child")

Comment: @Scotts if i dont make the child absolute it gives me a messy layout of the child divs. the child divs are not of equal heights

Comment: How exactly should it behave on click? Is selector_for_other_element referring to the previous or to the next? In other words, should the first element in the HTML be the leftmost in the result or the rightmost? Or should it all expand at once?

Comment: Can you update this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gizmovation/WWAuS/ so it better illustrates your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if this http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/CRRV5/ is exactly what you wanted, but it works and it can be tweaked.